# making the y-axis of a histogram probability, python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have plotted a histogram in python, using matplotlib and I need the y-axis to be the probability, I cannot find how to do this. For example i want it to look similar to this http://www.mathamazement.com/images/Pre-Calculus/10_Sequences-Series-and-Summation-Notation/10_07_Probability/10-coin-toss-histogram.JPG

Here is my code, I will attached my plot aswell if needed

```
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    mu = np.mean(a) #mean of distribution
    sigma = np.std(a) # standard deviation of distribution
    n, bins,patches=plt.hist(a,bin, normed=True, facecolor='white')
    y = mlab.normpdf(bins, mu, sigma)
    plt.plot(bins,y,'r--')

    print np.sum(n*np.diff(bins))# proved the intergal over bars is unity

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Please add your data (or code to generate it), and add your plot.

Answer (score 2):

Just divide all your sample counts by the total number of samples.  This gives the probability rather than the count.

Answer (score 1):

As @SteveBarnes points out, divide the sample counts by the total number of samples to get the probabilities for each bin.  To get a plot like the one you linked to, your "bins" should just be the integers from 0 to 10.  A simple way to compute the histogram for a sample from a discrete distribution is `np.bincount`.

Here's a snippet that creates a plot like the one you linked to:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


n = 10
num_samples = 10000

# Generate a random sample.
a = np.random.binomial(n, 0.5, size=num_samples)

# Count the occurrences in the sample.
b = np.bincount(a, minlength=n+1)

# p is the array of probabilities.
p = b / float(b.sum())

plt.bar(np.arange(len(b)) - 0.5, p, width=1, facecolor='white')
plt.xlim(-0.5, n + 0.5)
plt.xlabel("Number of heads (k)")
plt.ylabel("P(k)")

plt.show()
```

[image: plot]